# Let $G$ be a finite group and $f$ a non-trivial automorphism of $G$ such that for each $x\in G, f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=x^{-1}$. Prove that $G$ is solvable.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

I've been working on a group theory problem but hit a roadblock, and I'd appreciate some guidance.

The problem revolves around a finite group $G$ and a non-trivial automorphism $f$ in $G$. Specifically, for every element $x$ in $G$, $f(x)$ is either $x$ or $x^{-1}$.

I'm attempting to demonstrate that $G$ is a solvable group, indicating it can be systematically reduced to its identity element. I've made some initial attempts, identifying fixed elements under $f$ and those transforming into their inverses, but I'm struggling to tie everything together to prove the group's solvability.

Any hints, strategies, or insights on how to proceed further would be immensely helpful! Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: "systematically reduced to its identity element" ? Meaning that is derived series ends in the identity element, I suppose...

Comment: Is $f$ arbitrary? That is, is every automorphism of the group of either of those forms?

Comment: @Shaun If there *exists* a non-trivial automorphism $f$ with this property, then $G$ is solvable (we then have $f^2=id$, etc.).

Comment: Maybe it's obvious, @DietrichBurde, but I don't see it at the moment. Thank you though. Also, I suspect this has been asked before, though I can't find it.

Comment: @Shaun The first sentence of the question is indeed not clear. So I understand your question. The statement in the title is better, but should we written within the text.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $H = \{ x \in G \mid f(x)=x \}$. Then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and, since $f$ is nontrivial, there exists $g \in G \setminus H$.

Then for all $h \in H$, $gh \not\in H$, and so $f(gh) = g^{-1}h= (gh)^{-1} = h^{-1}g^{-1}$ and hence $g^{-1}hg=h^{-1}$. So $H$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $G$, and since the induced action of $f$ on $G/H$ inverts every element, $G/H$ is abelian. So $G$ is metabelian and hence solvable.

Comment: Why is $\;H\;$ a subgroup? Cannot be $\;x,y\in H\;,\;\;f(xy)=(xy)^{-1}\;$ ?

Comment: $f(xy) = f(x)f(y) = xy$.

Comment: Of course ..:) Thanks.